# Is there an R function for appending the lists with unequal columns

Tags: r

I have a below lists (with sublists as well). But here the columns are unequal. "a" list has 2 columns and "b" lists has 3 columns.

```
f <- list(a=list(1,2.5,9.5),b=list("2","-true","3",4))
```

I need to append this list keeping references like below. For example,

```
COl1  COl2  COl3  Col4
 a     1    false   NA
 b     2    true    3
```

As you can see above, there is a reference in col 1 from where the data object the lists is taken. Please guide

Comment: In the new example, please check your 'true" is corresponding to 2.5.  Could be a typo.  Otherwise `f %>% map(~ map(.x, ~  as.character(.x) %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE)) %>%map_if(is.integer, as.numeric)  %>% set_names(paste0("COL", seq_along(.x))),.id = "COL1")` should work

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to set the `names` of the `list` elements using `map` and specify the `.id` as 'COL1' to create a new column based on the `names` of 'f'.  Note that `map` returns a `list`, while `map_df` a `tb_df/data.frame`

**1)**

```
library(tidyverse)
f %>%
   map_df(~ set_names(., paste0("COL", seq_along(.)+1)), .id = 'COL1')
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  COL1   COL2 COL3  COL4 
#  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#1 a         1 false <NA> 
#2 b         2 true  3
```

---

**2)** If the types are different, `retype` (from `hablar`) and then do

```
library(hablar)
f1 %>%
   map_df(~ set_names(.x, paste0("COL", seq_along(.)+1))  %>% 
            map(retype), .id = 'COL1')
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  COL1   COL2 COL3   COL4
#  <chr> <int> <chr> <int>
#1 a         1 false    NA
#2 b         2 true      3
```

---

**3)** Or with `type.convert`

```
f1 %>%
   map_df(~ map(.x, type.convert, as.is = TRUE) %>% 
           set_names(paste0("COL", seq_along(.x))), .id = "COL1")
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  COL1   COL1 COL2   COL3
#   <chr> <int> <chr> <int>
#1 a         1 false    NA
#2 b         2 true      3
```

---

**4)** if the `integer/numeric` is giving an issue, then convert it to common type ie. to `numeric`

```
f1 %>%
  map_df(~ map(.x, type.convert, as.is = TRUE) %>% 
            map_if(is.integer, as.numeric) %>%
            set_names(paste0("COL", seq_along(.x))), .id = "COL1")
```

---

**5)** As the types are mixed up, it may be better to do the `retype` after converting to a single data.frame

```
f %>% 
  map_df(~ map(.x, as.character) %>%
          set_names(paste0("COL", seq_along(.x) + 1)), .id = "COL1") %>% 
  retype
```

#### data

```
f <- list(a = list(1, "false"), b = list(2, "true", "3"))
f1 <- list(a=list(1,"false"),b=list("2","true","3"))
```

Comment: Perfect, But lets say b is now ("2","true","3"). I am getting the error                     Error: Column `COL2` can't be converted from character to numeric. I have reframed by question. Please check

Comment: @Vinay Incase you have to change the example again, please let me know

Comment: I am getting the below error, Error: Column `COL2` can't be converted from character to integer

Comment: @Vinay I am not getting the error with the updated solution

Comment: because earlier b=list(2,"true","3") and now it is b=list("2","true","3") , So I am getting this error

Comment: because data in b is b=list("2","true","3"). 2 is under quotes. and it is not a number. SO this error is

Comment: @Vinay Is that the example you updated now.  It is working fine for me

Comment: @Vinay I updated with one more method.  Both are working fine

Comment: Hi Akrun, Yes it is working. But the issue my data is huge and the example i gave is just a sample. When I apply the code to my dataset, I am getting this error " Error: Column `COL2` can't be converted from character to integer"

Comment: Earlier error was Error: Column `COL2` can't be converted from character to numeric. The difference is only numeric and integer. Cannot we overcome any datatypes?

Comment: @Vinay I can only give solution based on the example you showed.  One option would be to create another `map_if` i.e. `%>% map_if(is.integer, as.numeric)` inside the loop

Comment: Hi Akrun, thanks for the code. But similar to " map_if(is.numeric, as.character) %>% " I tried for Date " map_if(as.Date, as.character) %>%. But getting error. Because in my data, date is converted to numbers and I do not want that to happen. can you help me to keep the date as it is

Comment: @Vinay You can check `mtcars %>% mutate(Date = Sys.Date()) %>% map_if(is.Date, as.character) %>% str`

Comment: There is no function called is.Date. I did not find it while coding

Comment: sorry, it is in `lubridate`, I loaded it

Comment: I tried with Mutate, But got this error Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "list"

Comment: @Vinay  It is working for me with the `data.frame` object as you can find it in my comment.  If you have a list of data.frame then as in the answer, do `map(lst1, ~ .x %>% mutate_if(is.Date, as.character))`

Comment: Now i tried with only with map_if(is.Date, as.character) . It worked. I did not use mutate at all. Would this be fine?

Comment: @Vinay `map_if` returns a `list`, while `mutate_if` returns the data.frame .  Depends on what you want

Comment: Hi. Akrun, i tried, Still i get the number 40980 instead of 12-03-2012. I need the date here instead of 40980. Hope your getting my point

Comment: I also tried with map_if(is.Date, as.Date). But no result

Comment: @Vinay  Your date format is not in the correct `Date` format.  You need to first convert it to that, otherwise it is already `character` format

Comment: Oh you mean to say while extracting the files only it needs to be converted? But how do I convert to date format?

Comment: @Vinay `as.Date(df1$yourcolumn, "%d-%m-%Y")` assuming it is day-month-year format

Comment: THanks. As you said, I used map_if(is.numeric, as.character) to make whatever number is, that should be converted to character. But I see some cells are reflecting like it starts with "  '- Safety  procedures  " So can we code so that whatever the cell has, it needs to be extracted? Because there are around 300 files and it will be difficult to search.Like can we code the special character to characters. I am figuring out. Hope you got my point.

Comment: Akrun, I have edited the question for you. There it is -true. So when i merge the list, these value is not coming

Answer (score 1):

**1) data.table** Set names on the list giving the new list `fnam` and then use `rbindlist` from data.table:

```
library(data.table)

fnam <- lapply(f, function(x) setNames(x, paste0("COL", seq(2, length = length(x)))))
cbind(COL1 = names(f), rbindlist(fnam , fill = TRUE))
```

giving:

```
   COL1 COL2  COL3 COL4
1:    a    1 false <NA>
2:    b    2  true    3
```

**2) base R**  This alternative uses no packages.  We create a character vector out of `f` and then read it in using `read.table`.

```
Lines <- paste(names(f), sapply(f, paste, collapse = " "))
nc <- max(lengths(f)) + 1
col.names <- paste0("COL", seq_len(nc))
read.table(text = Lines, header = FALSE, fill = TRUE, col.names = col.names)
```

giving:

```
  COL1 COL2  COL3 COL4
1    a    1 false   NA
2    b    2  true    3
```

Use some separator not appearing in the data if the data can contain spaces.

Comment: thanks. But there is no reference here. I need the data object "a" and "b" in one of the columns so that we can understand from these data objects the data is coming

Comment: Added that now.

Answer (score 0):

How about another simple base R solution.

```
f <- list(a=list(1,2.5,9.5),b=list("2","-true","3",4))
m = matrix(NA,ncol=max(sapply(f,length)),nrow=length(f))
for(i in 1:nrow(m)) {
  u = unlist(f[[i]])
  m[i,1:length(u)] = u
}
your_data_frame = as.data.frame(m)
```